# How to repeat every 3rd element of a vector?

Tags: arrays, matlab, vectorization

I have a vector like this:

```
h = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

And I want to repeat every third element like so:

```
h_rep = [1,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,9,9,10,11,12,12]
```

How do I accomplish this elegantly in MATLAB?  The actual arrays are huge, so ideally I don't want to write a `for` loop.  Is there a vectorized way to do this?

Comment: Did any of our answers help?

Comment: Timings for the solutions here would be interesting...

Comment: @gnovice I'm going to time all of the solutions tonight and will edit my post.  Thanks for the idea!  BTW, I think Luis's solution will be the fastest... he only uses indexing.

Answer (score 6):

One way to do this would be to use the recent [`repelem`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html) function that was released in version R2015b where you can repeat each element in a vector a certain amount of times.  In this case, specify a vector where every third element is a 2 with the rest of the values being a 1 as the number of times to repeat the corresponding element, then use the function:

```
N = numel(h);
rep = ones(1, N);
rep(3:3:end) = 2;
h_rep = repelem(h, rep);
```

Using your example: `h = 1 : 12`, we thus get:

```
>> h_rep

h_rep =

     1     2     3     3     4     5     6     6     7     8     9     9    10    11    12    12
```

---

If `repelem` is not available to you, then a clever use of [`cumsum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) may help.  Basically, note that for every three elements, the next one is a copy of the previous element.  If we had an indicator vector of `[1 1 1 0]` where `1` is the position that we want to copy and `0` tells us to copy the last value, using cumulative sum or `cumsum` on repeated versions of this vector - exactly `1 + (numel(h) / 4)` will give us exactly where we would need to index into `h`.  Therefore, create a vector of ones that is the length of `h` added with `1 + (numel(h) / 4` to ensure that we make space for the duplicate elements, then make sure every fourth element is set to 0 before applying the `cumsum`:

```
N = numel(h);
rep = ones(1, N + 1 + (N / 4));
rep(4:4:end) = 0;
rep = cumsum(rep);
h_rep = h(rep);
```

Thus:

```
>> h_rep

h_rep =

     1     2     3     3     4     5     6     6     7     8     9     9    10    11    12    12
```

One last suggestion (thanks to user [@bremen_matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3309610/bremen-matt)) would be to [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) your vector into a matrix so that it has 3 rows, duplicate the last row, then reshape the resulting duplicated matrix back to a single vector:

```
h_rep = reshape(h, 3, []);
h_rep = reshape([h_rep; h_rep(end,:)], 1, []);
```

We again get:

```
>> h_rep

h_rep =

     1     2     3     3     4     5     6     6     7     8     9     9    10    11    12    12
```

---

Of course the obvious caveat with the above code is that the length of vector `h` is evenly divisible by 4.

Answer (score 6):

(Modified according to rayryeng's correct observations)...

Another solution is to play around with the reshape function. If you reshape the matrix to a 3xn matrix first...

```
B = reshape(h,3,[])
```

And then copy the last row

```
B = [B;B(end,:)]
```

And finally vectorize the solution...

```
B(:).'
```

Comment: Couple of comments: (1) You can specify `[]` instead of `numel(h)/3` in the last argument of `reshape` to automatically compute the number of columns you need.  (2) The OP may want a row vector, so transpose `B(:)` after you're done.

Answer (score 4):

You can use just indexing:

```
h = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]; % initial data
n = 3; % step for repetition
h_rep = h(ceil(n/(n+1):n/(n+1):end));
```

Answer (score 3):

An index-based approach (using [`sort`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html)):

```
h_rep = h(sort([1:numel(h) 3:3:numel(h)]));
```

Or a slightly shorter syntax...

```
h_rep = h(sort([1:end 3:3:end]));
```

Comment: Interesting approach with `sort`!

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do it:

```
h = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
h0=kron(h,[1 1])
h_rep=h0(mod(1:length(h0),2)==0 | mod(1:length(h0),3)==2)
```

Answer:

```
1     2     3     3     4     5     6     6     7     8     9     9    10    11    12    12
```

Explanation: 
After duplicating every element, you select only those that you wants. You can extend this idea  to duplicate second  and third. etc..

Comment: The downside of copying *every* element and then deleting the unwanted ones, is a lot of computational and memory overhead.